# Generate folder structure of a changeset after checkin in VSO

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to generate a folder structure of all modified files in the solution after I do a check in to Visual Studio Online from Visual Studio 2013.

Is this possible using powershell or VSO, tfs ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the files changed for a particular changeset, you can use the ["get changeset" power tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f).

For example:

```
tfpt getcs -changeset:42
```